# How to add variables in a form textarea

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I would like to create custom confirmation messages that could be easily updated by the admins.

Like

```
 <textarea>You can contact {contact_name} located at {contact_place}…</textarea>
```

contact_name and contact_place are fields that will be completed in the same form, and are both required.

Is it something easy to manage?

Comment: don's think you would be able to achieve this with PHP. If understood correctly, you would like to fill contact_name and contact_place on the fly once the corresponding fields are filled in the form. Is that right?

Comment: Not exactly. For example, in my view(), I would like to identify {contact_name} and {contact_place} and replace them dynamically with the appropriate fields, for example event->name and event->place.

Comment: if you have data in a variable at the time of generating the form you could stick it in HTML like so: 
`<textarea>You can contact <?= $event->name?> located at <?= $event->place ?></textarea>`. 
Or do you generate your form using `<?= $this->Form->control('textarea_field_name') ?>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the text string with placeholders in db, then use  [str_replace](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_str_replace.asp) in **[custom Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers)** or in entity **[virtual fields](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields)**

```
   return str_replace(
      [
         '{{contact_name}}', // placeholders
         '{{contact_place}}', 
         '{{email}}',
      ],
      [
         $contact->name, // inputs
         $contact->place,
         $contact->email,
      ],
       // load template string from db
      // You can contact {{contact_name}} located at {{contact_place}}…
      $admin->template
   );
```